# How to configure appender to roll every 5 minutes in logback

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I want to implement appender which rolls every 5 minutes. How can I achieve it?
Here is the code:
Currently, it rolls every 1 minute

```html
<appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <file>myfile.log</file>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>${MY_PATTERN_HERE}</pattern>
  </encoder>

  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>myfile.log.%d{dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
      <maxFileSize>300MB</maxFileSize>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    <maxHistory>1000</maxHistory>
  </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Comment: This post may be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58617939/4581618

Comment: I saw that post, however, I would like to know is there better way to do it without custom AppenderPolicy